# How to accept this alert in appium?

Tags: java, ios, appium

Appium v1.6.4-beta
Xcode 8.2
macOs Sierra 10.12

I want to automate to save photo in my device.
But in first time I have to give permission. 
I have used "accept alert", but cannot accept the alert for allow to access the photo library.
It shows the test passed in green , when I execute the test, but this popup still appear in view and photo is not saved.

This is my script

```
//Check Save 
driver.findElement(By.id("Save")).click();
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Capabilities also used ,

```
 capabilities.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
```

This is what I want to allow

[image]

How to accept this alert?
I have tried with xpath sa well, but no luck

Answer (score 2):

Below code will work.Give it a try with "OK" and "Ok". This is because if you want to try to identify the element with the text you can use accessibilityID or ID.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("OK")).click();
```

Below code won't work for alerts coming in mobile automation like web alerts.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case, I handle alert of iOS Safari by change context to NATIVE_APP. Then find ID of "Open" to click. 
After that, I need to back to WEBVIEW_** context by driver.context(driver.getContextHandles().toArray()[1]);